# Jquery Plugin For Hover/highlight function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, menu, hover, highlight

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin that will execute the following use case.

I'm building a menu system that consists of 60 or so small rectangles fixed to the bottom of the page, these menu items I wanted to link to 60 blocks of content. When the user hovers on one of these menu rectangles, I need the connected block of content on the page to be highlighted in some fashion.

See this mockup below for a better idea of what I mean:

[image: screenshot]

I have searched extensively for a plugin that can handle the below, I did find the official jQuery highlight function but found it to perform poorly.

Comment: I don't think I would use a plugin for this, but it really depends what you want to do. Do you want to change the content on hover (show a container with some text in or suchlike), or animate the rectangles, or change colours and so on. What is your intention?

Comment: Yes, my apologies for assuming I'd need a plugin for this. When I hover over one of the rectangles, I'd ideally like a custom css style (box-shadow, background color overlay) to applied on-top of one of squares. The effect would be the same on all the squares.

Answer (score 0):

So apologies for the delay, I've made a very basic fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/TcuGf/

Basically there are lots of elements with the class hidden, which have the css property display:none, I made a very crude hover function which finds the parent of the hidden element which is rolled over and then slides down the hidden element.

Obviously you will need to tweak this to suit your needs, but the function should work for all containers.

This is the function:

```
$('.rect').hover(
   function(){
     $(this).find('.hidden').slideDown('slow');
   },
   function () {
     $(this).find('.hidden').slideUp('fast');
   }
);
```